# Set scrollView height dynamically

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview, xcode4.5

I m a newbie to iphone development and this is my first question.

I m displaying a UITableView in UIScrollView and I could not specify the height for both tableView and scrollView because the data is not static and it comes from services.

I need scrollView to set its height dynamically according to the content(height)of tableView.
I have done this but I couldn't see the last cell complete data.

```
self.tableView=[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,327,480) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    self.tableView.delegate=self;
    self.tableView.dataSource=self;
    self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    [testscroll addSubview:self.tableView];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(self.tableView.frame.origin.x, self.tableView.frame.origin.y, self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.tableView.contentSize.height);
    float ftbl = self.tableView.frame.origin.y + self.tableView.contentSize.height + 150;
    scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320, ftbl);
    scrollView.scrollEnabled=YES;
```

Im calculating height of tableview :

```
  - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

        UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView: self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath];

        NSString *city = lblcity.text;
        UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0];
        CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(280.0f, MAXFLOAT);
        CGSize bounds = [city sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];


        NSString *state = lblstate.text;
        UIFont *font1 = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0];
        CGSize constraintSize1 = CGSizeMake(280.0f, MAXFLOAT);
        CGSize bounds1 = [state sizeWithFont:font1 constrainedToSize:constraintSize1 lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];



        NSString *name = lblname.text;
        UIFont *font2 = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0];
        CGSize constraintSize2 = CGSizeMake(280.0f, MAXFLOAT);
        CGSize bounds2 = [name sizeWithFont:font2 constrainedToSize:constraintSize2 lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];



        NSString *address = lbladdress.text;
        UIFont *font3 = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0];
        CGSize constraintSize3 = CGSizeMake(280.0f, MAXFLOAT);
        CGSize bounds3 = [address sizeWithFont:font5 constrainedToSize:constraintSize3 lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

      return (CGFloat) cell.bounds.size.height + bounds.height+bounds1.height+bounds2.height+bounds3.height;



    }
```

How can scrollView increase/decrease its height according to the height of UItableview?

EDIT:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

   static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"Cell";

        UITableViewCell* cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if(cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault    reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];

            lblname = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
            lblname.tag = 111;
            lblname.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            [lblname setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14]];
            [lblname setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
            [cell addSubview:lblname];


            lbladdress = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
            lbladdress.tag = 113;
            lbladdress.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            [lbladdress setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12]];
            [lbladdress setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
            [cell addSubview: lbladdress];



           lblcity = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
            lblcity.tag = 115;
            lblcity.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            [lblcity setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12]];
            [lblcity setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
            [cell addSubview: lblcity];




            lblstate=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
            lblstate.tag = 116;
            lblstate.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            [lblstate setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12]];
            [lblstate setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
            [cell addSubview: lblstate];







        }

        cell.accessoryType= UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
        NSMutableDictionary *d =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary: [providerarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        NSString *name2 = [d objectForKey:@"Name"];
        CGSize constraint1 = CGSizeMake(175, 2000.0f);
        CGSize size1 = [name2 sizeWithFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14] constrainedToSize:constraint1 lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        lblname = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:111];
        lblname.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",name2];
        [lblname setNumberOfLines:0];
        lblname.frame = CGRectMake(105,25, size1.width, size1.height);



            NSString *lane2 = [d  objectForKey:@"Address"];
            CGSize constraint3 = CGSizeMake(175, 2000.0f);
            CGSize size3 = [line2 sizeWithFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12] constrainedToSize:constraint3 lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
            lbladdress = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:113];
            lbladdress.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",lane2];
            [lbladdress setNumberOfLines:0];
            lbladdress.frame = CGRectMake(105,lblname.frame.size.height+lblname.frame.origin.y, size3.width, size3.height);



                NSString *city2 =[d  objectForKey:@"City"];


                NSString *trimmedString = [city2 stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                                           [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
                NSLog(@"%@", trimmedString);
                CGSize constraint5 = CGSizeMake(175, 2000.0f);
                CGSize size5 = [trimmedString sizeWithFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12] constrainedToSize:constraint5 lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
                lblcity = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:115];
                lblcity.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",trimmedString];
                [lblcity setNumberOfLines:0];
                lblcity.frame = CGRectMake(105,lbladdress.frame.size.height+lbladdress.frame.origin.y, 175, size5.height);


        NSString *state1=[d objectForKey:@"State"];

        CGSize constraint6=CGSizeMake(175,2000.0f);
        CGSize size6=[state1 sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]  constrainedToSize:constraint6 lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        state=(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:116];
        [state setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",state1]];


        state.frame=CGRectMake(105, lblcity.frame.size.height+lblcity.frame.origin.y, size6.width, size6.height);
        [state setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
        [state sizeToFit];



           return cell;
    }
```

Comment: Hey,Why are you taking tableview in scrollview?Tableview itself scrolls when you scroll it up or down...Can you elaborate your question my friend?

Comment: but I dont want to set scroll for tableview.yes tableView itself has scroll.But if the data is large I do not know how many cells does tableView support in a view and what to do if the cells are many(how to set height of it dynamically)?

Comment: but it doesn't matter how many data tableview contents, it automatically creates heights of tableview.If you have say 10 data then tableview height will be enough to display 10 data and if you have 100 data then also tableview height will be enough to display 100 data, what you have to set is its numberOfRowsInSection method and cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: I have done that also.But it is displaying the cells only fit to height of view i.e 480.Beyond that it is not displaying.What else should I need to do?

Comment: ok,please post your code of cellForRowAtIndexPath method...

Comment: I have edited my code.Can u please have a look

Comment: My address height is 30 but when I see in heightForRowAtIndexPath it shows 15.Y is it so?Is it the right way to calculate heightforrow?

Comment: you have written  self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;, make it YES, then check it.Let me know it is working or not!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I would observe the table view's contentSize property and adjust your scroll view's height based on that.  For example:

Suppose you have your table view.  You can observe its content size like so:

```
[self.tableView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize" options:0 context:NULL];
```

Now, you can add this method to your view controller:

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {



}
```

Inside of this method, you can add some logic to see what observed value was changed, and then adjust your scroll view's height.

```
if (object == self.tableView) {

    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"contentSize"]) {

        CGRect scrollViewFrame = self.scrollView.frame;
        scrollViewFrame.height = self.tableView.contentSize.height;
        [self.scrollView setFrame:scrollViewFrame];

    }

}
```

Finally you can remove the observer in dealloc.

```
-(void)dealloc {

    [self.tableView removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize"];

}
```

Comment: But it is not entering in this -(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {  How do I need to call it?